# pygame line disappears when centre is drawn offscreen

Tags: python, pygame

I'm having an issue where my lines disappear when their centre is drawn offscreen, I want them to still be visible as their width enters the screen. Is there any easy way to solve this?

This is a recreation of the problem

[Where it Fits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTXQ6.png).
[image]

[Where it doesn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZKjP.png)
[image]

Here's the code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 600))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    WIN.fill((200, 200, 200))
    pygame.draw.line(WIN, (128, 128, 128), (x + 48, y - 24), (x + 48, y + 24), width = 48)
    pygame.draw.line(WIN, (128, 128, 128), (x - 48, y - 24), (x - 48, y + 24), width = 48)
    pygame.draw.line(WIN, (128, 128, 128), (x - 24, y + 48), (x + 24, y + 48), width = 48)
    pygame.draw.line(WIN, (128, 128, 128), (x - 24, y - 48), (x + 24, y - 48), width = 48)
    pygame.display.update()
```

I know rect objects work fine but is there no way to do this with a line?

Comment: As your lines are all horizontal or vertical it would be pretty straightforward to just limit x+y to 0<x>width etc.

Comment: @JeffUK The problem is the thickness of the line (`width = 48`). The center (axis) of the line is offscreen.

Comment: @Rabbid76 if you draw them all in a spiral around your square instead of radially, you can control the width and centre-distance such that the centre is always in the screen.

Comment: @JeffUK I see. Nice idea. It's worth an answer, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, but I'm afraid there is no "easy" way. I mean, there isn't a switch that you can turn on or off.

The simplest solution is to draw rectangles instead of a lines:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 600))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    WIN.fill((200, 200, 200))
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (128, 128, 128), (x-72, y-24, 48, 48))
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (128, 128, 128), (x-24, y-72, 48, 48))
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (128, 128, 128), (x+24, y-24, 48, 48))
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (128, 128, 128), (x-24, y+24, 48, 48))
    pygame.display.update()
```

---

If you want to draw lines, the first thing that comes to my mind is drawing the entire scene onto a slightly larger Surface. Finally [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) this surface on the screen. Unfortunately, with this solution you have to shift oll the objects in the scene by a certain offset:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 600))
offset = 48
virtual_win_rect = WIN.get_rect().inflate(offset*2, offset*2)
virtual_win = pygame.Surface(virtual_win_rect.size, pygame.SRCALPHA)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x += offset
    y += offset

    virtual_win.fill((200, 200, 200))
    pygame.draw.line(virtual_win, (128, 128, 128), (x + 48, y - 24), (x + 48, y + 24), width = 48)
    pygame.draw.line(virtual_win, (128, 128, 128), (x - 48, y - 24), (x - 48, y + 24), width = 48)
    pygame.draw.line(virtual_win, (128, 128, 128), (x - 24, y + 48), (x + 24, y + 48), width = 48)
    pygame.draw.line(virtual_win, (128, 128, 128), (x - 24, y - 48), (x + 24, y - 48), width = 48)
    
    WIN.blit(virtual_win, virtual_win_rect)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: This seems to work very well! Should I then use this new surface when using blit and pygame.draw for other things in my program?

Comment: @Dorje Unfortunately you have to. However, I think JeffUK will come up with an even better solution. Just rotate all the squares by 90° or draw rectangles.

Comment: @Dorje I've extended the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Edit.  Rectangles don't have this problem,  so you could do this instead:

```
pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (128, 0, 128), pygame.Rect(x-72,y-24,48,48))
pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (128, 0, 128), pygame.Rect(x-24,y-72,48,48))
pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (128, 0, 128), pygame.Rect(x+24,y-24,48,48))
pygame.draw.rect(WIN, (128, 0, 128), pygame.Rect(x-24,y+24,48,48))
```

If you really want to do lines.. you could draw the lines in a different orientation, then you can control their width to ensure they never go off the screen.  (x_offset would actually be y_offset in the top and bottom cases...)

[image]

i.e.

```
line_width = max(48,distance_to_edge)
offset = line_width/2
```